# Certificate has expired error in Insomnia REST client

Tags: api, rest, rest-client, insomnia

I'm using `Insomnia REST` client to work with api's.

I want to connect to **Git** on gitlab/github but I have this error:

```
Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1501:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:710:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can workaround the issue by disabling Validate Certificates in insomnia `preferences`.

[image: preferences]

Comment: Does anyone know of a solution that isn't a workaround?